# How to share files or folders across different user accounts on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, file-sharing

I have some files with an user account.I would like to share some of the files to another user on the same MAC. I copied the files to Public folder,but I am not able to view the files in the other account.Later I enabled the file sharing to read and write,still I am not able to view any files in the Public folder.How to enable file sharing so that I can view and modify the files across the given user accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by the following method.

Copy all your files you want to share to "Computer Name/Macintosh HD/Users/Shared".

Now all of your users on the same Mac would be able to read the contents of that folder.

Comment: No. Only the one who copied the file has _write_ access. Other users has only _read_ access.